# repeat values from selected option in menu and in similar selected menus Java Script, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have the following select menu that will be repeated 8 times by php for loop. I want, using js, to set onchange event to repeat the selected option from the first menu in the rest of the 7 menus, and off course repeat the value of the option as well. Given that I read the select menu values for mysql table:

```
for ($a=1; $a<=$n; $a++) 

{ 
readtable_no_order ("rooms"); //php function to read table
echo '<select name="hOffers['.$a.']'.'" class= "select">';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected"></option>';
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{echo '<option value ="'. $row['room'] . '">'. 
  $row['room'] . '</option>';}
  echo '</select><br>';

 }
```

THANKS in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demonstrating on the "rendered" html (IE8+):

```
<select name="hOffers[0]" class= "select">
    <option value="room_1">Room 1</option>
    <option value="room_2">Room 2</option>
    <option value="room_3">Room 3</option>
</select>

<select name="hOffers[1]" class= "select">
    <option value="room_1">Room 1</option>
    <option value="room_2">Room 2</option>
    <option value="room_3">Room 3</option>
</select>

<script>
    var selectBoxes = document.querySelectorAll( '.select' );

    for ( var i = 0; i < selectBoxes.length; i += 1 ) {
        selectBoxes[i].onchange =  function( event ) {
            var currentValue = event.target.value;

            for ( var j = 0; j < selectBoxes.length; j += 1 ) {
                selectBoxes[j].value = currentValue;
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4fxBB/

I believe there will not be a problem echoing that script tag after your select boxes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking for.
However, this code snipet is not really good.
You should return objects from your php functions and handle the html with loops in your page.

something like:

```
<?php
    $objectList = myFunctionToGetObjectList();
    for ($objectList  as $object) 
    {
?>
<select name="<?php echo $object.someValue; ?>" class="select">
...
</select>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Then in javascript, you could add javascript events using getElementsByTagName